# Delete certain mis-spelled words from Android dictionary (These words were not listed in the "Personal dictionary")

Tags: auto-correct, dictionary

I have a Sony Ericsson Xperia mini (running Android 4.04). I'm trying to remove a few embarrassing words which show up during typing. I tried through **Settings** → **Language and input** → **Personal dictionary**. When I checked the **Personal dictionary**, I see that there are no such words listed, though there is an option to add new words to this list. I added a few words and then afterwards I could delete them also. But I couldn't find any way to delete those words which come up during typing messages etc.

I might previously have typed those wrong spellings accidentally, and I think through the **Learn new words automatically when typed** feature the words have been added to the main dictionary.

Is there any way to remove them from there? I don't want to turn off the auto-complete/suggestions feature completely.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going into personal dictionary, try all languages, which on my phone is right above the personal dictionaries option. That's where my list of words was.

Comment: A screenshot would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround: You can type similar starting words couple of times to make your phone think they are more frequent. Embarrassing words will not disappear but they will not bother you because new words will be suggested instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes switching what type of english "US->UK" may result in a prediction focus.

I say this because it was driving me NUTS that abd would come up instead of and when I swipe the text in.

Same thing with the word hell, US english doesn't like that word, it will change it to he'll. I thought I could just remove "he'll" from my dictionary, but alas it depends on switching to a more secular language.