# Stop auto correction of dont to Dont

Tags: keyboard, auto-correct, gboard

I've got almost the same question as [the one here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61115/how-do-i-remove-an-incorrect-word-from-autocorrect) however the accepted solution is not working for me.

Whenever I type the word ***dont*** the google keyboard automatically corrects it to ***Dont*** (capitalizes the D).
In the word suggestions it shows the correct auto correct *don't* to the right of the three suggestions above the keyboard. Additionally if i write *dont* at the start of a sentence the auto correct comes out as *Don't* which is correct. And finally lets say I type *sont* accidentally, the word does get auto corrected to *don't*, again correctly. So why the word *dont* auto corrects incorrectly I don't know.

As per the example question the accepted answer was to clear the data for the keyboard, which I have done, but it doesn't change this behaviour...This surely can't be default behaviour of the keyboard can it?

p.s. If it matters this is with the UK english keyboard on 4.4.2

Comment: Can you long press the 'Dont' in the suggestion box (above the top row of keys) and remove it manually? I Dont (ha ha) have Google Keyboard installed (I don't like it) and this works on SwiftKey and others, worth a shot! Weirdly all of them do suggest 'Dont' as a word though!

Comment: No unfortunately long pressing the word only brings up a popup area of a load of other suggested words. I'd try another keyboard, but I've always liked the stock one, and now that it has it's own version of swype I don't have any gripes with it, apart from the aforementioned.
p.s. like the pun ;)

Comment: It's a know issue: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/WPC-UjKkeQA the suggestions there probably won't help but I'll keep digging! The generic advice is: Head over to the Google Keyboard settings, and and tap the Personal dictionary option. Add a new word to the dictionary by using the + symbol. You will now get a pop-up window where you can enter your phrase, and a shortcut to expand that phrase.

Now, whenever you type that shortcut in any text-input field, it will be automatically expanded to the phrase you wanted.

Comment: If you go to `Settings > Language & input > Settings Icon beside Google Keyboard > Personal Dictionary` can you remove `Dont` from there?

Comment: I've only got one word in the personal dictionary, and `Dont` is not it, and I just tried adding `dont` to the dictionary which doesn't auto correct to `don't` however it does stop it correcting to `Dont` which is a start I gues...

Comment: Ok last thing I can think of "Instead of going into personal dictionary, try all languages, which on my phone is right above the personal dictionaries option. That's where my list of words was." From http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40197/delete-certain-mis-spelled-words-from-android-dictionary-these-words-were-not-l?rq=1 If this doesn't work someone else needs to step in! This shouldn't be so difficult!!

Comment: Hmm, that menu item doesn't exist on my system. At least not anywhere I can see. Above personal dictionary I've got spell checker [checkbox] and then the item to switch language. Doesn't appear below either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your contacts. Keyboard will search and suggest contact names.

Comment: Ha, unbelievable. That was actually it. I had a contact saved as *Dont Answer* from a long time ago, so I removed it and cleared the keyboard data and hey presto it now auto corrects correctly! Shame I use swiftkey now anyway.